Mackie cr4-x studio monitors cutting audio when the input volume is too low
So I bought these used active studio monitors recently and use them with trs cables connected to my SSL2 audio interface. Everytime a track gets too quiet they cut the audio to a barely noticable volume (no matter what source, DAW, Spotify etc). I have to turn up the input to unpractical amounts of volume so they don't act that way.
Can I do something about that or did I just buy trash?
Greetings from Germany!
-Thomas
